# Parse json object from table via php connected to phpmyadmin

Tags: json, parsing, phpmyadmin

I'm using a json-parser in Xcode to fetch a table from phpmyadmin. The parser gets (or should get) the json-formated document via a php-file uploaded on my ftp-server. The file is successfully parsed but it doesn't recognize any objects. I think this is because there are multiple arrays in the json-document.

When there's only one entry the document looks like this: 
    [{"id":"1","Name":"Eric","Message":"first from web"}]

but when i add an entry it looks like this:
    [{"id":"1","Name":"Eric","Message":"first from web"}]
[{"id":"1","Name":"Eric","Message":"first from web"},{"id":"6","Name":"Claes","Message":"Hurrburr"}]

As you can see the old array (containing only the single entry) is still there in the second array with both entries.

I suspect the problem is that the old arrays are still there when i update the database because when i tried parsing the json document with only one entry (only one array) it worked.

So my question is first if there´s something i missed in my code, or if you know why the old arrays are still there when I update the database or how to remove all previous arrays when the document is updating.

Here is my .php-file:

```
<?php

$username = "perhaps not sharing this information";
$password = "or this";
$database = "nah";

mysql_connect("the server url",$username, $password);

@mysql_select_db($database) or die("Error here");

$query = "SELECT * FROM debug_db";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

$num = mysql_numrows($result);

mysql_close();

$rows = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
$rows[] = $r;

echo json_encode($rows);
}

?>
```

And check out the json-document at: http://app.levinnovation.se/getjson.php

Thank you!

Comment: Move the line `echo json_encode($rows);` to below the `}`. (swap the last two line of your code.)

Comment: And this I´ve been trying to fix for like six hours, gaaah! Thank you so much for the answer, it did the trick!